# using arbitrary width pixels not working when deployed on prod tailwind css, postcss, next

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss, css-purge

using specific pixel width (e.g. `w-[50px]`) with tailwind CSS and nextjs but when deployed to production (on Vercel) the specified width doesn't show up, locally it works fine. Is there something wrong with my posts configuration that's causing it to not read tailwind's arbitrary width values?

here's my `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "tailwindcss",
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? [
          "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
          {
            content: [
              "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
              "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
              "./stories/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            ],
            defaultExtractor: (content) =>
              content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
          },
        ]
      : undefined,
    "autoprefixer",
  ],
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  variants: {
    extend: {
      opacity: ["disabled"],
    },
  },
};
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

nextjs version -- `"next": "12.1.0"`

purgecss version -- `"@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.1.3`

tailwind CSS version -- `^3.0.18`

the `NODE_ENV` has also been set to `production` on Vercel when deployed and checked on production

Comment: Try removing the PurgeCSS configuration from `postcss.config.js`. Tailwind CSS will take care of purging unused styles if you use `content` in its config.

Comment: that worked thanks! any pointers on how to understand how the purging works underneath? i'm not sure how postcss and tailwind are working together here